# Is it possible to make direct ethernet connection between machines with iOS and Fedora? How?

Tags: linux, networking, macos, ethernet

I am trying to connect Macbook and notebook with Fedora using ethernet cable in order to make HTTP request, so far with no success. I am also unable to find any sufficient tutorial (for beginners at least).

For now I'd like to be able to at least ping between the devices.

Comment: Do the notebooks have IP address? What are you trying to ping using?

Comment: 1) Google how to set up a static address both on MacOS and Linux (`ifconfig`, `ip addr ...`). 2) Run a DHCP server (easier on Linux). 3) Read up on `tcpdump` and `wireshark`, google a generic networking tutorial (LAN segments, static/dynamic addresses), read all of it, and learn how it works by looking at actual packet exchanges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly connecting two devices with ethernet requires a crossover cable or a ports which can auto-sense this.  Aside from that, it's fairly basic, assign them two different class C private addresses (192.168.1.x) with a 255.255.255.0 subnet, and ensure firewalls etc are turned off.  You'll have to use their IPs for any sort of communication, and not hostname, as there will be no DNS with this config.